# Updating ownCloud got stuck - recover?

Tags: owncloud

Yesterday I wanted to update my ownCloud isntallation from version 7 to 7.0.1 (or 7.0.0a - I can't recall the exact name...).
I triggered the update using the intrgrated update mechanism. Unfortunatelly it seems to get stuck since I still get the page stating "The ownCloud instance is currently being updated...".

Is there a way to get the installation going again without having to reinstall from scratch?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether you can get the installation going again, but I've just seen this post here: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/10195. May be this is related to your problem? It seems to me, that you would need to start a new installation in this case.

Comment: Actually that helped! I didn't have to reinstall. All that was necessary was to set the property maintenance in the file config/config.php to false and after trying to enter the application it asked me to execute the update what then also worked without any issues. Thanks!